# OO design struggle

Tags: c#

There is one thing I cannot seem to get my head around.
So I'm looking for some input.

I have an Invoice class that can print a report or show it as a preview on screen.
Before I can print or preview it I have to load the data from the invoice from the database.

The invoice class looks basically like this:

```
public class Invoice{
    private int _invoiceID;

    public Invoice(int invoiceID){
        _invoiceID = invoiceID
    }

    public bool LoadData(){
        (loads info from the database into the report)
    }

    public bool Print(){
        (Prints the report to the printer)
    }

    public Report Preview(){
        (Returns the report for previewing)
    }
}
```

My question is, do I call LoadData inside my Print and Preview method?
Then I would make LoadData a private function, but I cannot unit test it anymore. If you would call Print and Preview at the same time for the same invoice, it would LoadData twice for the same invoice.

Do I keep it as a public function?
Then I would have to call it after I instantiate my Invoice class and before I call Print or Preview, with the danger of forgetting to call LoadData.

Do I put it in the constructor?
Again making it private would make me loose the ability to unit test. And it doesn't seem correct to do this in the constructor.

Or do I have to move this Print and Preview options to another class?

Your idea is appreciated!

Comment: This is very opinion based. That said, you should look a the responsibilities of the class (Single Responsibility Principle) and its  concerns (Separation of Concerns) . `LoadData` could be extracted out into an explicit dependency. That should solve the flexibility problems you are encountering. You should get familiar with SOLID principles.

Comment: In this scenario I might introduce a flag, `_loaded`, used like this: `void LoadData() { if (!_loaded) { LoadDataFromDatabase(); _loaded = true; } }` - that way `LoadData()` can be safely and efficiently be called multiple times.

Comment: I also believe from a model/domain perspective that `Invoice` class is doing too much.

Comment: Agree that the Invoice class is doing to much. I would want to separate the data itself from the functionality to load it and create reports. Additionally, since you ask about putting the loading into the constructor, putting non-trivial functionality into a constructor can make unit-testing difficult.

Comment: If you want to look into unit testing, you're going to have to start with dependency injection. You currently have hardcoded all your behaviors which makes it nigh impossible to properly unit test.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably extract the functionality into two separate classes, `Invoice` hold all invoice data and is returned from the database. `InvoiceReport` handles print and preview. I guess these two do very similar work. If not you could extract them even further.

```
var invoice = store.GetInvoice(invoiceId);
var invoiceReport = new InvoiceReport();
var preview = invoiceReport.Preview(invoice);
var result = invoiceReport.Print(invoice);
```

Comment: In this scenario InvoiceReport isn't holding any state data so may as well be a collection of static functions.

InvoiceReport(Invoice) makes more sense here,

Comment: I real world probably you would use dependency injection. And InvoiceReport would implement an interface that you would inject when you need to print/Preview. This also makes it a lot easier with testing.